# PHP: Calculations drops the end 0?

Tags: php

I'm not sure if anyone could help here but I'm just doing simple calculations using PHP to get a total value of a shopping cart.

However, the issue that I have right now is that sometimes the total is like this:

```
£10.50 or £10.60 etc etc..
```

but for some reason PHP changes the value to `10.5 or 10.6` etc...

is there something that I need to do specifically to stop this happening?

I'm not sure if you guys require to see my calculation but as I said its a very simple calculation like so:

```
$pricetotal = $price * $each_item['qty'];
$cartTotal = $pricetotal + $cartTotal;
```

any help would be greatly appreciated..

EDIT:

I've tried this:

```
setlocale(LC_MONETARY, en_GB);
$cartTotal = $cartTotal;
$cartTotal = money_format(LC_MONETARY, $cartTotal);
```

but this doesn't seem to work! it changes a value of `9.50 to 4`!

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.money-format.php

Comment: `var_dump($cartTotal)` BEFORE you do the money_format call.

Comment: What does the statement $cartTotal = $cartTotal; do?

Answer (score 2):

Use the money_format:

```
echo money_format('%.2n', $cartTotal);
```

If, for some reason, your locale format isn't set, you can precede this with

```
setlocale(LC_MONETARY, en_GB);
```

That is for Great Britain - you can change it to your personal locale.

For reference, the manual has very many examples of how for format currency: http://php.net/manual/en/function.money-format.php

Comment: Thanks. I began thinking about setting the locale and mixed the two together while I was typing.